# How to read OTP from Email using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, one-time-password

I am automating a webpage where for Registration, otp gets sent to Email for verification. I want to fetch OTP from Email & print on textfield.

Please advice.

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking. Please read the [SO guide on how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly

Answer (score 3):

The code below can be used to fetch OTP from Outlook mail box, similar smtp can be used for the all other mail boxes.

```
public static String OutlookMailReader(String mailFolderName,String emailSubjectContent, String emailContent, int lengthOfOTP) {

            
//mailFolderName(Eg- "INBOX"), emailSubjectContent(Eg- Mail for OTP),
emailContent(Eg- OTP is 111111), OTP length(Eg- 6)
            String hostName = "smtp-mail.outlook.com";//change it according to your mail

            String username = "****@***.com";//username 

            String password = "*******";

            int messageCount;

            int unreadMsgCount;

            String emailSubject;

            Message emailMessage;

            String searchText=null ;

            Properties sysProps = System.getProperties();

            sysProps.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");

            try {

                Session session = Session.getInstance(sysProps, null);

                Store store = session.getStore();

                store.connect(hostName, username, password);

                Folder emailBox = store.getFolder(mailFolderName);

                emailBox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

                messageCount = emailBox.getMessageCount();

                System.out.println("Total Message Count: " + messageCount);

                unreadMsgCount = emailBox.getNewMessageCount();

                System.out.println("Unread Emails count:" + unreadMsgCount);

                for(int i=messageCount; i>(messageCount-unreadMsgCount); i--)

                {

                    emailMessage = emailBox.getMessage(i);

                    emailSubject = emailMessage.getSubject();

                    if(emailSubject.contains(emailSubjectContent))

                    {

                        System.out.println("OTP mail found");

                        String line;

                        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(emailMessage.getInputStream()));

                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                            buffer.append(line);

                        }

                        String messageContent=emailContent;

                        String result = buffer.toString().substring(buffer.toString().indexOf(messageContent));

                        searchText = result.substring(messageContent.length(), messageContent.length()+lengthOfOTP);

                        System.out.println("Text found : "+ searchText);

                        emailMessage.setFlag(Flags.Flag.SEEN, true);

                        break;

                    }

                    emailMessage.setFlag(Flags.Flag.SEEN, true);

                }

                emailBox.close(true);

                store.close();


            } catch (Exception mex) {

                mex.printStackTrace();

                System.out.println("OTP Not found ");

            }

            return searchText;

        }
```

Explaination:
mailFolderName(Eg- "INBOX"), emailSubjectContent(Eg- Mail for OTP),
emailContent(Eg- OTP is 111111), OTP length(Eg- 6) as my activation code is 6 digits.

The code checks for outlook mail and checks for the recent unread mail for mail with subject(Eg : OTP mail). Opens the selected mail and returns the OTP

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible approaches that you can take.

## 1. Retrieve the OTP directly from the app

Think of the normal end-user workflow. The OTP must be generated **and stored** somewhere in your app, so that when the user logs back in with the OTP, it can be verified by the app. You should be able to work with your devs how and where to retrieve the OTP from the database, likely using a [jdbc](/questions/tagged/jdbc) connection.

To make this cleaner, you can ask development to expose an API (only in test?) that you can use to fetch the OTP.

This is probably the simpler option.

## 2. Use a light-weight mail server

In your test environment you can configure a light-weight email server, something like [MailHog](https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog) which does not have a complicated login procedure, and has a straightforward API to access any email.

This option requires a change of configuration in your test environment, but it gives you the option to also test the entire contents of the email that is sent out.